# Does Captain Marvel have this power in "Endgame"?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In the beginning of *Avengers: Endgame* (and some of the teasers) when Captain Marvel turns to look at Thor who then summons his axe to intimidate her, you can hear in a whisper voice

> I have telepathy.

at 0:49.

This isn't mentioned or used in the film that I can see. Why is it there and is there any significance?

Comment: I've just damaged my hearing by watching the clip you posted on top volume. She says nothing, her lips don't move, and why would she even say that at that moment? It's completely out of context and would sound ridiculous.

Comment: The "whisper" you are hearing just sounds like part of the music and to go from some indistinguishable noise to _"I have telepathy."_ is a huge nonsensical leap.

Comment: "Why is it there and is there any significance?" - How about "Marvel misdirection"

Comment: I listened again and actually this time I heard what you’re talking about. I can see (hear!) why someone might think those words are being said, but I still think it’s obvious it’s just random sounds.

Answer (score 5):

Long story short, nope, it seems to be a mix of sounds and audio and montage... Some people [freaked out on Reddit as well](https://www.reddit.com/r/MarvelStudiosSpoilers/comments/bb18h1/if_you_turn_up_your_volume_you_can_hear_someone/ekgeb48/), and a user who supposedly knows their way around sound mixing says there's a mixture of sounds giving that effect, but it's not an actual spoken line.

> I've worked a bit in sound engineering (unprofessionally) and decided to do a bit of work on this "voice". I listened through this section probably about 100 times while EQing and adjusting the play speed and have concluded that the initial sound (the one that makes up the "I" sound people are hearing) is the beginning of a breath/sigh from Thor. Its frequencies match very closely to the sigh we hear later in the clip after he sets down Stormbreaker. [...]
>
> TL;DR: Through some sound manipulation, it's likely we're hearing a set of noises that make up this "whisper". Another Yani/Laurel situation. [...] I'll have to experiment further, but this is DEFINITELY human pattern recognition.

Add to that that telepathy isn't in Captain Marvel's skillset (not her MCU version at least) and it didn't make it to the movie (it's a trailer montage thing). Sure, trailers have been shown to deliberately mess with viewers at times, but here... It would make zero sense. Stuff happens, and we hear a lot of things when we're hyped.

Comment: It DID make it to the movie because I was listening for it in the real scene. However, that doesn't discredit that it's a trick of the mind in both cases.

Comment: @IronSean ah, I did not remember that music in the film. If you say so :) I'll update that answer whenever the clip gets released on YouTube, anyway. And yeah, minds play on us ahah